# Solve 404 error when hosting netcore 2.1 web api in IIS

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm publishing .netcore 2.1 web api project in IIS but i'm getting 404 error. I can run application from Visual studio and its working with swagger.

already installed netcore 2.1 runtime, restarted environments, selected "No Managed Code" in my application pool but still getting 404 error.

my launchSettings.json looks likde this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:65391",
      "sslPort": 44318
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "QAAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my Startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
               {
                   c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info { Title = "QA API", Description = ""});

               }
            );

        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI( c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "QA API");
                }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Make sure you are uploading the site to the correct folder on your server. As troubleshooting mechanism, add simple static html (index.html) at the root of the folder where you are trying to put your site. If you can't access index.html, perhaps the issue is with the location

Comment: `launchSettings.json` has no bearing. That's only used for uses of `dotnet run` (i.e. when running in Visual Studio, for example). Once published, it's no longer used. A 404 is what it is: the resource you're looking for isn't there. If there was some issue or exception, you'd get something in the 500 range. Check the IP/port/domain bindings in IIS, ensure you're using whatever virtual path is necessary, if it's deployed to a virtual path. Ensure that the the app is actually deployed to the correct site, etc.

Comment: @yibe yes i tried this and can't access to index.html. but where is the problem

Comment: @ChrisPratt tested in local machine, target location is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\qaapi. configuration in IIS is port 80 and app location is same as target.

Comment: Have you installed IIS correctly? Is it running in the Windows Services?

Comment: @yibe it is working with empty application, hosted only index.html and i have access with localhost:80. but when i published .netcore web api it gives me 404 error. also iis_iusrs have read/write access.

Comment: Run a report https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html and paste it as part of your question so others can see how you configured.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the application pool identity in the IIS settings?

[image]